# Facebook-style API access scenario with Azure ACS and OAuth 2.0: how to implement app authorization?

Tags: wcf, rest, oauth, azure, acs

I am building a social website that will expose REST API (WCF WebAPI) to the world so any developer would be able to create a client application for the website, integrate it with other services, etc.

I would like to implement Facebook/Twitter-style access control mechanism for the API. So that developers will register their apps on the developer section on the site, create a key and use that app key in OAuth workflow to get access to the API.

Since I use Azure in this project, I consider leveraging Azure ACS to facilitate OAuth processes. However, I am unable to find any code sample or manual for app authorization with ACS.

Can someone share such example or at least give me a direction for my own research? If I can achieve Facebook/Twitter behavior with another OAuth library (e.g. DotNetOpenAuth), that would be cool, too.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ACS is a good choice for this sort of thing. Your scenario is pretty much OAuth Delegation, which ACS supports.

You should look into ACS with OAuth 2 Delegation sample in:

https://connect.microsoft.com/site1168/Downloads (It is called Wif Oauth CTP version)

Note that in this sample custom authentication is used for autheticating the user. Since ACS provides Single Sign On with Idps, you can instead use ACS here (e.g with Facebook).

If you go this path, you can find more information on how to use a custom home realm discovery page in the following sample:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127794.aspx

Finally, you will neeed to have a web page where your client apps will manage their settings. For this you will be required to use ACS management service. You can find detailed information on using ACS management service in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185970.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have reviewed the sample you kindly pointed me to. It is kind of relevant but it is not much helpful anyway. It contains so much programming code, particularly on the  WebClient part so that I wonder why I really need ACS (paid service!) along with WIF to do OAuth. It does not make things much simpler.

What I really need is simple URL-based workflow explained on this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/ Can I implement similar approach with ACS?

Comment: Alex you should more concentrate on the Authorization Server code instead of Web Client.

The answer for your question is yes. But it won't be just doing some setup in the ACS portal. You will need to write half of an OAuth Authorization Server, and you will need to write an account management web front end for your clients.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that I will need to write some code. The reason I am so concerned with Web Client code is that I aim to making API access as easy as it's done in Facebook: I simply redirect user to a page on Facebook where user logs in and authorizes the app. When he/she finished, I just receive the token. No extra round trip to the server for an authorization code. No complicated logic on client-size. Just a single GET request -- and I have the token. I went through a few ACS code samples, docs and labs and no one helped me figure out how to implement such a simple scenario.

Comment: Okay, I found a few classes that provide SWT ticket encoding/validation/decoding, and I decided to implement a simpler version of OAuth workflow myself. It turned out not as complicated as it seemed at first :)